# Delete DB row using ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

each of my rows have a detele button next to them that should delete it.
Problem is that after I click it, nothing happens and I have no idea why.

Does it maybe have anything to do with the fact that the ID is set to AUTO_INCREMENT?

So I used MySQL to do the tables:

[image]

Then I created a webpage that translates the code into this:

[image]

And finally, this is the code:

```
<?php

    include('connect-mysql.php');

    $sqlget = "SELECT * FROM kunden";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('Error!');

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>KundenID</th>.....<th>Telefon</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['kundenid'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        .......................
        .......................
        echo $row['telefon'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo '<button onclick="window.location=delete.php?id='.$row['kundenid'].'">Delete</button>';
        "</td></tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";

?>
```

And my delete.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
      // delete the row based on the `id` parameter
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      mysqli_query($dbCon, "DELETE FROM kunden WHERE kundenid = ".$id);

}
?>
```

Comment: is `delete.php` in this question not completely posted?

Comment: What? Seriously, the "shortest code necessary to reproduce it" is shown in the post above. Also in the first sentence, I have clearly stated what the problem is and why I think it doesn't work for me. This -1 is completely misused in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I suggest just submit the form normally instead of creating a redirection:

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="delete.php">';

    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>KundenID</th>.....<th>Telefon</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['kundenid'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            .......................
            .......................
            echo $row['telefon'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<button type="submit" name="delete" value="'.$row['kundenid'].'">Delete</button>';
            "</td></tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";

echo '</form>';
```

Then on `delete.php`, don't forget to connect. Its not inside the question anyway:

And since its mysqli, why not use prepared statements:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

    $dbCon = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
    $id = $_POST['delete'];
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM kunden WHERE kundenid = ?';
    $delete = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
    $delete->bind_param('i', $id);
    $delete->execute();

    if($delete->affected_rows > 0) {
        header('Location: back_to_telefons_page.php');
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is very clear, also is there a simple way to refresh the page instead of echo 'deleted'?

Comment: @BogdanLazar yes of course, you could just delete that echo, then redirect back to that page `header('Location: backtothatpage.php'); exit;`